# How to create multiple rows (as date column) into CTE? (out of thin air)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored-procedure and I want to add date column to the tables.  Then I wonder how do I get MS-SQL to generate multiple rows on the fly using CTE.  Say I have this..

```
(GETDATE() - 548)  --(365 days --> 12 months, 548 days --> 18 months...
```

How do you guys whip up a query that would create 548 rows and have the date column as row

```
#1 - '12/17/2012'
#2 - '12/16/2012'
#3 - '12/15/2012'
```

etc. all the way to row #548?  All of that into a CTE?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, it sounds like you want the following:

```
;with dates(value) as
(
    select DATEADD(d, -548, cast(getdate() as DATE))
    union all
    select DATEADD(D, 1, value)
    from dates
    where DATEADD(D, 1, value) <= cast(getdate() as DATE)
)
select *
from dates
order by value desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7256)

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks so much!!